# Validating associated models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am currently working on a diet tracking app. I have a FoodEntry model where each instance references a single `food` from another table, and also references a unit of `measurement` from yet another table.

```rb
class FoodEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :measurement
  validates :food, presence: { message: 'must exist' }
  ...
end
```

That works fine, but the thing is that each entry in the `measurements` table is set up (because I'm working with external data) to be associated with a certain `food`, i.e. a measurement belongs to a food, and a food has many measurements:

```rb
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :measurements
  ...
end

class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  ...
end
```

My question is, what is the correct way to validate that the specific `measurement` I'm referencing in a `food_entry` is also one of its `food.measurements`?

Currently in my `FoodEntry` model I'm doing this:

```rb
validate :measurement_must_be_associated

def measurement_must_be_associated
  unless food.measurements.include? measure
    errors.add(:measurement, 'is not associated with that food')
  end
end
```

This custom validation works, but I'm not sure it's the cleanest way to do it.

I attempted to do this instead:

```rb
validates :measurement, inclusion: { in: food.measurements }
```

but this gives me an error when calling `FoodEntry.new(food_id: 1, measurement_id: 1)` in the rails console (actual `id`s are irrelevant):

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `food' for FoodEntry (no database connection):Class
```

Using `in: self.food.measurements` in the validation made no difference. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
validates :measurement, inclusion: { in: ->(record) { record.food.measurements } }
```

`validates` is a method defined on a class, and is being evaluated when a class is declared. Normally, when inclusion values are known before program starts (and are static), passing value is sufficient - validator (which is being created when `validates` is called) simply saves the passed object and uses it when validating.

In your case the inclusion values are unknown at the point when validator is created (and they also depends on the validating object). Hence, you need to pass a lambda, so validator can use it to get inclusion values during a runtime.

Note also, that validator object is attached to a class, not to a particular instance, so lambda needs to have record param.